# Как задать таймаут для GET-запроса

Tags: c#, xnet

Использую библиотеку `xnet.dll`

```
Parallel.For(0, numbers.Count, new ParallelOptions {
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1
   }, (j) => {
    req.ConnectTimeout = 10000;
    req.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000;
    rz = req.Get("https://xxx.ru.xhtml?objId=" + numbers[j]).ToString();
```

Я хотел параллельно запустить в 10 потоков, однако выводит ошибку

```
 System.NotSupportedException: "Вызов метода Write невозможен, если другая операция write находится в режиме ожидания."
```

GET-запрос для данной страницы очень долго выполняется, так как сайт тормознутый. Если я работаю в один поток, то все работает отлично.

```
в System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   в System.Net.Security.SslStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   в xNet.HttpRequest.SendRequest(HttpMethod method, Uri address, HttpContent content, Boolean reconnection)
   в xNet.HttpRequest.Raw(HttpMethod method, Uri address, HttpContent content)
   в xNet.HttpRequest.Raw(HttpMethod method, String address, HttpContent content)
   в xNet.HttpRequest.Get(String address, RequestParams urlParams)
   в XXX.Form1.<>c__DisplayClass3_2.<button1_Click>b__1(Int32 j) в c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\XXX\XXX\Form1.cs:строка 86
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<ForWorker>b__1()
```

Comment: Ну вам же русским по белому говорят, что ваш `req` не потокобезопасен. Почему вы не заведёте в каждом потоке по штуке? Экономия на спичках при запуске космической ракеты?

Comment: Использование `xnet.dll` вам необходимо?

Answer (score 1):

Вы создаете один объект req для множества потоков.

Чтобы все работало независимо необходимо создавать объект req для каждого потока, 
т.е. создание объекта должно быть в цикле Parallel.For, а не за пределами его.

И не забывайте освобождать неуправляемые ресурсы, 
если таковые есть иначе будет утечка памяти.

P.S. для Вашей задачи не вижу смысла использования xnet.dll вполне достаточно использования HttpClient.
Например так:

```
    private async Task GetXXX(int appId)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync("https://xxx.ru.xhtml?objId=" + appId);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    data[appId] = Parse(result); // парсинг ваших данных в data
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }
```